# Concatenate two files in a loop to create new file?

Tags: python, bash

I'm trying to combine two lists. They are both in files named list1.txt and list2.txt. I'm trying to append the words in list2.txt to list1.txt. For example:

list1.txt has thousands of words like

- apple
- brother
- friend

list2.txt has around a dozen words like

- crust
- lake
- rain

I'd like to get an output that takes all words from list2.txt and concatenate them to each word in list1.txt. So the output would look something like this:

- applecrust
- applelake
- applerain
- brothercrust
- brotherlake

etc. I'm not sure how to get this done. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this may help you

```
List = []
list1 = open('list1.txt','r')
total = ''
for i in list1:
    List.append(i.strip())
list1.close()
for append_text in List:
    
    list2 = open('list2.txt','r')    
    for i in list2:
        final = str(append_text)+str(i)
        total = total+final
    total = total+'''\n'''
    list2.close()
print(total)
```

Comment: Thank you for this. This does the trick. Just out of curiosity, what would it look like if I wanted to add a third list?

Comment: Ok i can help you but can u explain what u want with the third list?Also please mark my answer if it had helped you

Answer (score 3):

Using `join` to get a cartesian product and `tr` to get rid of the delimiting space:

```
$ join -o 1.1,2.1 -j 666 file1 file2 | tr -d ' '
```

Some output:

```
applecrust
applelake
applerain
...
```

Solution is abusing the fact that there is no field 666 in the files and joining on a nonexisting field produces the cartesian product of the items in the files.

Comment: Thanks, @James Brown. This helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `zip()`:

```
with open("output.txt", 'a') as output:
    with open('file1.txt') as file1, open('file2.txt') as file2:
        for word1, word2 in zip(file1, file2):
            output.write(word1 + word2 + "\n")
```

What this does is, it opens, parses through them together and writes it to an output file.

Edit: This question has been upvoted, so I think this worked for you, but looking again onto your question I saw that you require a different output. Here is the revised code:

```
output = open("output.txt", 'a')
file1 = open('file1.txt')
file2 = open('file2.txt')
for word in file1:
    for second_word in file2:
        output.write(word + second_word + "\n")
    file2.seek(0)
output.close()
file1.close()
file2.close()
```

For each word in file1 it iterates through all the words in file2 and adds them together. Then it moves on to the next word in file1 and so on.

Comment: I don't think that will do what you need - you will get : 
applecrust
brotherlake
friendlane

you wont get any of the others.

Comment: Ahh I see. Didn't see that.

Comment: Your second code snippet will exhaust the second file immediately after the second for loop exits the first time.

Comment: The only sensible way to do this is to use `itertools.product()` - or read everything in each file into a list and do two loops.

Comment: lets hope you have a fast disk drive ;-) or small files - that is so uggh :-(

Answer (score 1):

I can't guarantee this will give you specific order but :

```
from itertools import product

with open("output.txt", 'w') as output:
    with open('file1.txt', 'r' ) as file1, open('file2.txt','r') as file2:
       for word1, word2 in product(file1, file2):
           output.write(word1.strip() + word2.strip() + "\n")
```

`itertools.product()` will give you every combination of words from the first file and words from the 2nd file.